# React native performance is too slow, after upgrading from 0.68.7 to 0.71.3

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, performance

I've complex components in my app.I previously ran it on 0.68.7, where it was really fast, but after upgrading to 0.71.3, performance dropped drastically, to the point that it is unusable.

Currently I've downgraded react native version to overcome this issue.Still this issue is not fixed in react native side. So is this okay to downgrade react native version
ISSUE LINK:https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36296#issuecomment-1702758607